# Allowing write only access to a log?

Tags: files, write

I am in the process of putting in place an audit log, for operations related to database modifying operations and url access. For various reasons, including preventing tampering and protecting sensitive information, I would like this to be 'write only' by the application. Maybe more specifically append-only?

Is it possible to do this on Linux and are there any things I should take into account when doing this or maybe a better way to go about this?